# Dynamic labeling looks awful in flex map

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, web-mapping, labeling, arcgis-flex-viewer

I published a service to ArcGIS Server 10.1 from an .mxd with no halos around the labels and created a flex application using the flex viewer. When I browse to the map [here](http://nwrpcmaps.nwrpc.com/LSWT/) and zoom in on an individual trail segment, the labels become very grainy and appear to have a white halo around them, making them very difficult to read. It becomes exceptionally noticeable when imagery is used as a basemap.

Is there any thing I can do to stop the labels from getting all messy looking or is this just how they look when using flex?

Comment: Do you have anti-aliasing turned on for your features in your map service?

Comment: My Anti-Aliasing settings are as follows:
Anti-Aliasing = none
Text Anti-Aliasing=forced

I tried changing these settings, clearing my browser cache, and revisiting the map but no luck on fixing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to standard web fonts. I've had luck with using Verdana black with white halos, if you want the halos.  But it appears you do not.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but wanted to share that I fixed this problem by caching my services using PNG32 format instead of PNG8.    I had tried changing my fonts prior to that and that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to be using the standard label engine and not Maplex. Maplex doesn't work well with ArcGIS services.

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be a simple change of font that fixed my problem.